# Regex to match white spaces before certain characters with some exceptions

Tags: regex

I have this regex `([ ][,.!?;:])` to check a string if there is a white space before some punctuation marks(,.!;:). It works quite well but I need an exception for colon (:) mark. I want a match just if the character after the colon is not a slash (/).

Comment: You can use this pattern: `(?!.* :\/)([ ][,.!?;:])`. also there's no need to put space in brackets, so pattern can converts to: `(?!.* :\/)( [,.!?;:])`

Comment: Please let me know if you saw the above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
([ ](?:[,.!?;]|:(?!\/)))
```

Or,

```js
(?! :\/)( [,.!?;:])
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/acHd4h/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/acHd4h/1).

*Details*:

- `[ ]` - a space (note the brackets are not useful here unless you have free spacing mode on (and not in Java)
- `(?:[,.!?;]|:(?!\/))` - either of

  - `[,.!?;]` - one of the chars in the set
  - `|` - or
  - `:(?!\/)` - a colon not immediately followed with a slash.

*Regex #2 details*

- `(?! :\/)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a space, then a colon and then a `/` immediately to the right of the current location
- `( [,.!?;:])` - Group 1: a space and then a char from the set.